# Recent posts from wordpress gallery

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to display recent images from wordpress gallery in the format like:

```
<div class="portfolio-item">
            <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                <a href="HERE LINK ON IMAGE" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><img src="img/zoom.png" width="58" height="58" alt="" title=""></a>
            </div><!-- .portfolio-overlay-->
            <img class="pi-img" src="HERE LINK ON IMAGE" alt="" title="">
        </div><!-- .portfolio-item-->
```

How i should build my loop?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the query results

```
"SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT ?"
// where ? is the number of rows you want to return
```

you can just do a simple foreach loop:

```
foreach ($galleryPic as &$pic) {
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use thumbs for posts ([read more about post's thumbs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)). Than in your category template use this loop:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <article class="post">
            <header>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <span class="date"><time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?>"><?php the_time('j F Y'); ?> <?php _e('в');?> <?php the_time('G:i'); ?></time></span>
                <span class="author"><?php _e( 'Author:', 'nikita-sp' ); ?> <?php the_author(); ?></span>
                <span class="category"><?php _e( 'in category', 'nikita-sp' ); ?> <?php the_category(', '); ?></span>
                <span class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( '0 comments', 'nikita-sp' ), __( '1 comment', 'nikita-sp' ), __( '% comments', 'nikita-sp' )); ?></span>
                <?php edit_post_link( "Edit", '<span class="edit">', '</span>'); ?>
            </header>
            <?php the_content('read more...'); ?>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
        <article>
            <h2><?php printf( __( 'SEARCH RESULT for: %s' ), '<span>' . esc_html( get_search_query() ) . '</span>' ); ?></h2>
            <p class="center"><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing was found', 'nikita_sp' ); ?></p>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </article>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also use thumb output where y want.

```
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```